# I am trying to extract a substring using regex_replace command . I want to extract “SWIFTInward” here

Tags: regex, powershell, ansible, trim, regexp-replace

I tried below code in Ansible

```yaml
---
- hosts: windows
  strategy: linear

  vars:
    war_file_path: F:\\Install\\IIBProjects\\DE\\WAR\\DE_SWIFTInward-202010.0.0.war

  tasks:
    - name: Get properties folder path for windows
      set_fact:
        endpointDetails: "{{ item | win_basename | regex_replace('\\\\(?:(?!\\\\).)*$', '') }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ war_file_path }}"
      register: war_file_name
      when: ansible_os_family == "Windows"
```

**Expect output**: `SWIFTInward`
**Error output which i am getting**: `DE_SWIFTInward-202010.0.0.war`

Comment: Please provide details on what you need to exclude at the end of the string: what is the expected pattern for `-202010.0.0.war` ?

Answer (score 1):

The [`win_basename`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names) returns the file name without the directory details. So, your regex does not match it as it requires a `\` at the start.

You need

```py
endpointDetails: "{{ item | win_basename | regex_replace('^[^_]*_([^_-]+).*', '\\1') }}"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DdHnVE/1)

Or, use `regex_search` with a simple `_([^_-]+)-` [regex](https://regex101.com/r/DdHnVE/4):

```py
endpointDetails: "{{ item | win_basename | regex_search('(?<=_)[^_-]+') }}"
```

**Details**

- `^[^_]*_([^_-]+).*`:

  - `^` - start of a string
  - `[^_]*` - zero or more chars other than `_`
  - `_`  - a `_` char
  - `([^_-]+)` - Group 1 (`\1`): one or more chars other than `_` and `-`
  - `.*` - the rest of the string.
- `(?<=_)[^_-]+`:

  - `(?<=_)` - a location in string that is immediately preceded with `_`
  - `[^_-]+` - one or more chars other than `_` and `-`.